# Blunt Talk, Shrubby Barquentine

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, geography, history

[image: Blunt Talk, Shrubby Barquentine]

Clues:

I stand in the East, facing West in all directions
A day’s sail, just across the line
Unlucky year, a ship ran aground...

A different world, different age
Set the stage, elemental alias...

[contextual images] [backwards 'h'] [arrow down from h] [pointers: famous buildings]

Name That Character:

_ _ N _ _ _ _ _ _

Hint:

> Try rereading the first line while thinking with two hemispheres.

Hint:

> By "hemispheres", I mean "planetary hemispheres".

Hint:

> None of the puzzle will make sense until you can decipher the first line.

Comment: Why doesn't this puzzle have any mention of where it's from? Given the "difficulty level" in the picture, it must be from some site or book, but that's not mentioned

Comment: This puzzle is original by me. Not in a book anywhere. Perhaps the difficulty level should be increased?

Comment: Initial thoughts on the first line: rot13(vfynaqf arne gur vagreangvbany qngr yvar (znlor gur yvar vfyrf rira). vs lbh ybbx jrfg sebz bar, lbh'er ybbxvat jrfg. vs lbh ybbx rnfg sebz bar, lbh'er ybbxvat gb gur 'Jrfg'. Jbhyq nyfb rkcynva gur frpbaq yvar). 

But I have no idea where to go from there if it is the case.

Comment: Also, along that line (and thinking of the final question): rot13(Oyhag Gnyx zvtug zrna fubeg fgbel? Nyfb jvgu gur yvar vfynaqf, gurer'f nyfb Syvag vfynaq (ersreraprf pcg. syvag va gernfher vfynaq znlor) naq Fgneohpx vfynaq (zbol qvpx) gung zvtug or yrnqf be erq ureevatf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I stand in the East, facing West in all directions
> A day’s sail, just across the line

This must refer to

> somewhere as far east as it's possible to go according to time zones, i.e. somewhere just on the left-hand side of the [International Date Line](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/International_Date_Line.png). Sailing just across the line would mean changing time zone by around 24 hours, hence "a day's sail".

Possibilities at this stage are

> Tonga, Samoa, Line Islands, Chatham Islands, ... maybe New Zealand if we're being a bit less literal?

---

> Unlucky year, a ship ran aground...

So we're probably looking for

> a shipwreck in a year like 1713/1813/1913/2013. [Samoa has a bunch of shipwrecks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Shipwrecks_of_Samoa) but not in those years; Tonga has [the Tongan castaways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongan_castaways) shipwrecked in 1965; the Chatham Islands [also have a bunch of shipwrecks](https://freepages.rootsweb.com/%7Enzbound/genealogy/chathams.htm); and the Line Islands have also had shipwrecks, including one after which [an atoll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmyra_Atoll) is named.

There's also

> the [Fiji](https://monumentaustralia.org.au/themes/disaster/maritime/display/30626-%22fiji%22) shipwreck - in Australia, but the ship was *called* Fiji, and Fiji is near the International Date Line too.

Another approach:

> we could look for shipwrecks in [2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shipwrecks_in_2013) or [1913](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shipwrecks_in_1913) or [1813](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shipwrecks_in_1813), but none of them look very promising. The only ones I found in the right kind of location were small incidents in Alaska, nothing well-known.

---

Except ...

> the [Amaranth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaranth_(barquentine)), a barquentine wrecked on **Jarvis Island** in 1913.

It fits the title of the riddle ("shrubby barquentine"), the unlucky year, and the location. So then the location we're looking for is

> Jarvis Island, sharing a name with [this character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J.A.R.V.I.S.). Fitting the clued "n" in the name we're looking for, it's probably **Tony Stark**, which would also fit with the "elemental alias" of Iron Man. (Thanks @Stiv for this last connection!)

The only things I don't yet get are "blunt talk", "different world, different age, set the stage", and the image. But maybe these things would make more sense with some specific popular culture knowledge that I lack. Anyway, it seems that the final answer is

> TONY STARK.

---

**OP edit:**

> The island you were looking for is called Kiribati. Standing here in the Eastern Hemisphere, you see the Western Hemisphere in all directions:
>
>  [image: location of Kiribati]
>
>  Zooming in to the island, we see something that looks like the backwards 'h'. Note Paris and London at the legs:
>
>  [image: map of Kiribati]
>
>  Align the backwards 'h' to the map and follow the arrow (not too far, because it's only a day's ride) to meet Jarvis Island, the final resting place of the [Amaranth Barquentine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaranth_(barquentine)).
>
>  "A different world, different age Set the stage" refers to the answer not being of history, but instead fiction.
>
> The word "Blunt" in the title is a synonym for "Stark".

Comment: I think you've hit upon the correct line of reasoning and it's just a short hop further to rot13(gbAlfgnex, svggvat gur rahzrengvba, jubfr 'ryrzragny' nyvnf vf bs pbhefr VEBA Zna...)

Comment: Thanks @Stiv, that seems like it!

Comment: Hm. And the  backwards letter is rot13(n "pncvgny U", fb ulqebtra naq Veba vf gb gur evtug naq qbja sebz vg. Ohg Sr qbrfa'g unir nalguvat qverpgyl bobir vg. Naq jul jbhyq gur u or onpxjneqf?) Or, perhaps, rot13(guvf vf n ersrerapr gb U.B.Z.R.E. nf qrfpevorq va gur yvax: U cyhf Ebzr, nabgure Rhebcrna pncvgny.) Okay, I'll stop now. I'm rambling.